# Как создать массив директорий в Perl?

Tags: perl

Допустим, имеется директория /dir, в которой имеется 3 директории: /dir1, /dir2, /dir3. Как можно создать массив, который бы содержал в себе полные пути трёх директорий?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@files = glob ('/path/to/dir/*');`

Comment: А можно то же самое применить к хэшу, но уже по отношению к файлам и их содержимому, чтобы получилось key=имя_файла, value=содержимое_файла?